# LASSO in AR-Models

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, lasso, autoregressive, elastic-net

I couldnt find such a post here. I am highly interested in applying the lasso to different situations. However, I am actually dealing with time series models of high order. I have found some research on the use of LASSO on AR(p)-processes and its asymptotic property as in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.1179.pdf). I am wondering why LASSO should be usefull in this sense.

My Intuition was that, if two or more relevant predictors are highly correlated, the lasso is choosing on of them arbitrarily. So an Elastic Net Approach would be superior.

Is my Intention wrong, that lasso would perform bad in AR cases caused by the correlation. The Simulation in the paper proves the opposite. Can someone help me to understand the idea of applying lasso in AR-models or give me some sources/research that are explaining it in more or less a simple but logic way. 
I appreciate any comment or discussion

Comment: There are some papers: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X10002186   http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.460.3911&rep=rep1&type=pdf many others! also R packages: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BigVAR/BigVAR.pdf  and others